# Flask Waitress Simple Webserver

Tags: python, flask, webserver

I am trying to set up a simple webserver. This is the simplified code.

```
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/data")
def get_data():
    return {"abc"[i]:i for i in range(3)}

if __name__=="__main__":  
    # app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

I can connect to this on my desktop and my phone (which is on my WiFi) and it works as desired.

The issue comes when a connection is attempted from a device not on my network (say a phone on a different network). The response is ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.

I setup an inbound rule in my firewall settings. I'm on a windows 10 OS right now if that matters.

- ProtocolType=TCP (it was default)
- LocalPort="Specific Ports" and 8080
- RemotePort="All Ports"

I also read I should set up port forwarding in my router so I followed [these](https://www.att.com/support/article/u-verse-high-speed-internet/KM1010280/) instructions from my ISP.

- It's in the Service List
- Global Port Range is 8080-8080
- Protocol is TCP/UDP (again, default)
- Host Port is 8080

I'm not sure what else I should change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for posterity.

My issue was some AT&T weirdness. I turned on IP passthrough in my router settings and other people can connect to the server.

If I run `ipconfig` in my cmd prompt, I get an IPv4 of A.B.C.D, but https://whatismyipaddress.com/ responds with E.F.G.H.

I can connect to A.B.C.D:8080/data from my computer but not the other IP.

Someone not on my IP can connect to E.F.G.H:8080/data from a different network but not the other one.

The final takeaway is that I should probably just use some sort of ns services like cloudflare.